# Changing the binding of a block

Tags: ruby, lambda, scope, proc

I am trying to write a class that can capture a block of code and subsequently change the variables in the scope/closure.

```
class BlockCapture

  attr_reader :block

  def initialize(&block)
    @block = block
    @scope_additions = {}
  end

  def merge_into_scope(values = {})
    @scope_additions = @scope_additions.merge(values)
  end

  def mutated_block
    # some code that merges the scope additions into the binding
    # and returns the context
  end
end

captured_block = BlockCapture.new do
  future_variable.upcase
end

captured_block.block.call # This should trigger a NameError, as `future_variable` is not in scope.

captured_block.merge_into_scope(future_variable: "I was added to the scope")

captured_block.mutated_block.call # This should work
=> "I WAS ADDED TO THE SCOPE"
```

I don't know how to go about merging the variables into the scope.

I have tried calling the binding method on the block variable, but it returns a new binding each time, so it appears to be a copy of rather than a reference to the binding of the original block.

```
irb(main):078:0> capture.block.binding
=> #<Binding:0x007fa38292e398>
irb(main):079:0> capture.block.binding
=> #<Binding:0x007fa382925f18>
irb(main):080:0> capture.block.binding
=> #<Binding:0x007fa38291d908>
```

Comment: Interesting. Are you sure you can do it? If the block is a closure, it should work in the environment (scope) of the moment of creation. For example: `l = -> { future_variable.upcase }` will not allow you to `l.call` when you define `future_variable` after the lambda. Yes, global works in this case, but globals are bad, mkey?

Comment: It is not clear to me how you want this to work. `@scope_additions` is a hash, so is the goal to create local variables in the block with the same names as the hash keys before the block is evaluated? I'm not sure if that's possible.

Comment: Exactly. Scope additions should be merged into the binding of the block.

Answer (score 0):

Positing as an answer, even if I am not sure it would be helpful, because there is no space in the comment. Looks like you can run eval with the specific binding, for example with the current binding, created **after** the lambda was defined:

```
bind_lambda = -> (bind, x) { bind.eval x }
#=> #<Proc:0x007fec943b85e8@(pry):1 (lambda)>
```

First try ends with an error, as expected:

```
bind_lambda.call binding, 'future_var'
NameError: undefined local variable or method `future_var' for main:Object
from (pry):2:in `__pry__'
```

But after declaration of the local variable:

```
future_var = "here be dragons"
#=> "here be dragons"
```

We can reach it:

```
bind_lambda.call binding, 'future_var'
#=> "here be dragons"
```

This is because `binding` is the current environment.

Comment: This is interesting, but it's not really a solution. The reason I need to do this is because the block is passed on to some library that cannot be instructed to pass arguments in when calling it. I cannot change the way the library invokes the lambda.

Comment: In [Ruby 2.1](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Binding.html) there is a method `Binding.local_variable_set` - I didn't try it but looks promising

Comment: I tried that. The problem is that my_proc.binding apparently returns a copy of the binding, rather than a reference and I haven't found a way to assign a new binding to a proc.